# Why am i getting Possible null pointer dereference in findbug?

Tags: java, findbugs

On the 5th line of below code spotted as a bug by the findbugs:

Possible null pointer dereference in com.xyz.common.CommonUtils.FolderNotEmpty(String) due to return value of called 
 method [Troubling(13), Normal confidence]

```
public static boolean FolderNotEmpty(String path) {
        boolean flag = false;
        File f = new File(path);
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            if (f.listFiles().length > 0) {
                flag = true;
                LOGGER.info("Folder - " + path + " is not empty.");
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Folder - " + path + " is empty.");
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("The given path is not a directory - " + path);
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition:

1. You call `f.isDirectory()`, which returns true.
2. I replace the directory at `path` with some ordinary file.
3. You call `f.listFiles()`, which returns null.

To avoid this, say `File[] files = f.listFiles();` unconditionally, and then change your `if` to `if (files != null)`. Better yet, reduce the nesting in your method this way:

```
public static boolean folderIsNotEmpty(String path) {
    File f = new File(path);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if (files == null) {
        logger.warn("not a directory");
        return false;
    }

    if (files.length > 0) { 
        logger.info("not empty");
        return true;
    } else {
        logger.info("empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

(Or, if you don't need the log statements, `return (files.length > 0)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `f.listFiles()` can return `null`. Rewrite it with following code:

```
if (f.listFiles() != null && f.listFiles().length > 0)
```

Comment: It’s basically correct. But I thought that `listFiles()` would not return `null` when `f.isDirectory()` is true?

Comment: @OleV.V. That's correct, but at the minimum there's a race condition in that `f` could be replaced between the `isDirectory()` and `listFiles()` calls. (Just like there's a race condition here, and potentially a serious performance problem.)

Comment: Since `f` is a local variable, there cannot be a race condition.

Comment: @DorianGray `f` is _a pathname corresponding to a file on the filesystem_. That file can change at any time.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried to use the same code still its shows the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

listFiles method of File class can return null. 
So you need to check if f.listFiles() return null at 5th line, otherwise, if (f.listFiles().length > 0) can cause NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  your code is perfectly safe.

> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise an array of File objects is returned, one for each file or directory in the directory.

That is exactly what you have covered.

However,  Findbugs cannot know about that contract. It just says there is a *potential* NPE. You can choose to ignore that.

Comment: This is not correct, as the accepted answer explains.